# Using CommonCrypto to generate a salted key

Tags: objective-c, c, security, cryptography, commoncrypto

This is how I have been generating my cryptographic keys until now:

```
unsigned char *salt; //8 salt bytes were created earlier
unsigned char *password; //password was obtained earlier
int passwordLength; //password length as well

unsigned char evp_key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = {"\0"};
unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

EVP_BytesToKey(cipher, EVP_md5(), salt, password,  //cipher is also given
               passwordLength,
               1, evp_key, iv);
```

The result is a key and an “initial value.” I can then use these two (`evp_key` and `iv`) along with the given cipher to encrypt my data.

Now that with Lion, Apple has deprecated the above code, I have the following question:

**Question:** How do I do the same thing with CommonCrypto? I just came across the `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF()` function. Is this the one I’m looking for? I can’t see how this is the case, since I don’t get any “initial value” back. I don’t know how to compare this CommonCrypto function with the old method.

**In particular:** This new function doesn’t seem to even support the MD5 algorithm—only the SHA1. How, then, can I create new code that is backwards compatible with my old codebase (and files it has created)?

Comment: Also see [Password to key function compatible with OpenSSL commands](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9488919/608639), which provides the code to do so in C and Swift. The other question appears to be a dup, but its has good answers with code. I think it adds more value for future visitors.

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. To me, it seems impossible to derive the keys exactly the way OpenSSL does using any Apple’s methods. Instead, I just had to read how OpenSSL derive the key and initialization vector in the section “Key Derivation Algorithm” on the page http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html and simply mimic that.