# OpenSSL EVP and CryptoJS

Tags: openssl, cryptojs, evp-cipher

CryptoJS is said to be OpenSSL compatible what can be noticed [running the demo](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#With_OpenSSL).

Now I want to implement the same behavior using the OpenSSL EVP API: chipher a string using a passphrase and exchange the result with CryptoJS which must be able to decrypt it (knowing the passphrase).

My doubt is about the standard way to exchange the iv (which I see as the key of CryptoJS and OpenSSL compatibility).

How am I supposed to send the iv along with the ciphered message?

PS: Please do not concern about client-side encryption/decryption because I am comfortable with the use case.

**Update**

Ciphering with OpenSSL command line tool

```
$ echo "Hello World" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:"Secret Passphrase" -e -base64
```

U2FsdGVkX18Z8dTy1NR6/gm+9IxmbuT8iCblIjvV76E=

Deciphering with CryptoJS

```
var de = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("U2FsdGVkX18Z8dTy1NR6/gm+9IxmbuT8iCblIjvV76E=","Secret Passphrase",{keySize: 256/32});

de.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); // output: Hello World
```

In my use case I want to cipher using the EVP API instead of openssl command line tool.
I am missing how to "package" the ciphered text, iv and salt altogether in one string as it was on "U2FsdGVkX18Z8dTy1NR6/gm+9IxmbuT8iCblIjvV76E="

**Update 2**

I took [the Saju Pillai example](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt) as start point.

**Update 3**

My problem is about "interchangeability" of the ciphered text.
I am getting the following parts

- **key :** 79A38D896D90DBFE5E151A326602BC3A4A9081F3F9BEAC08EF058B96BA51CF19
- **iv  :** 76614325D3DA73698DDD220431AE298E00000000000000000000000000000000
- **cipher text:** QfCKTtVPlDcTOhC5ylwKFQ==

I am looking to send a single string to the client which must be able to decipher the string and get the parts required to the decryption process (it is exactly what I observe between CryptoJS and OpenSSL)

Comment: The IV is a public parameter. You can send it with the encrypted message. Be sure the MAC covers *both* the IV and Message. Or, you can do like TLS and derive it from the master secret and keep it secret. There's arguments for/against handling the IV as public and as secret. I think wikipedia lists a few of them. Personally, I send it in the plaintext with the message.

Comment: OK, I just looked at the public interface in the reference you cited. This library is very limited. Without key agreement, its *really* hard (impossible?) to do things correctly. If you don't have the agreement schemes, then `key = PBKDF2(password)` always derives to the same key. That's not going to work - you need a unique key for every connection. Connections cannot share the same key.

Comment: Show us some code. We need to see how you are doing things like preparing a message before sending on the wire.

Comment: @jww Sorry, comments are tricky. Please refer to the Question update. Thanks a bunch

Comment: OK. there's a lot to it, and this should get you started. OpenSSL derives a key and IV from the password, and it does it in a non-standard way. To read about the `openssl enc` command, see OpenSSL's [`enc(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) docs. To see *how* OpenSSL is doing it, see the source code for the `enc` program in `<openssl source dir>/apps/enc.c`.

Comment: @jww thanks to pointing me the way. Do you have any clue about how OpenSSL (and CryptoJS, by the way) do this? If it is non-standard, what is the standard?

Comment: You might try starting here: [Openssl password to key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488919/openssl-password-to-key). Or, look at the CryptoJS source code. Google is also helpful: [openssl enc "-k" "EVP_BytesToKey" site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/#q=openssl+enc+%22-k%22+%22EVP_BytesToKey%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @jww I did update (Update 3) the question. I am not sure whether we were talking about the same problem. I was studying the enc.c and I could not figure out how and where they are dealing with the "packaging" of ciphered text, iv and salt in a single string.