# How to register PBE_KeyGen API into EVP Engine to support PBEWith<Digest>And<Cipher> algorithms

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am trying to implement my own PBE_KeyGen method in "C" for generating KEY and IV using the given digest and Cipher algorithms along with password and salt inputs in Openssl-evp.

While working on this got few examples which uses EVP_BytesToKey method for generating key and IV- [Password to key function compatible with OpenSSL commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488919/password-to-key-function-compatible-with-openssl-commands) but I want to implement my own keygen method and register that into EVP engine and use in PBE algorithms implementation.

Please suggest me with possible ways to achieve this and test.

Thanks
Rajesh